# What does it mean when we say that a periodic point is isolated?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I can't find a definition of what it means that a periodic point of $f$ is isolated, where $f$ is a diffeomorphism. Is this related to the existence of discontinuities of $f$ about the periodic point?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say if $p$ is the period of $x_*$, then $f^p$ has an isolated fixed point in $x_*$. That is, in some neighborhood no other point is a fixed point.

Comment: Thanks Lutz! That is great. Do you know by the way what the minimum number of $f^{(n)}$ is for $f$ to be a diffeomorphism, when $n$ is the degree of differentiation and $f^{-1}$ is the inverse, and $\exists$ $\big(f^{-1}\big)^{(n)} $?

Comment: For an otherwise unqualified diffeomorphism you need $C^1$, as the definition is for $f^{-1}$ to exist as function and it and $f$ being $C^1$. If there are qualifications such as "smooth", "analytic" or "$C^n$" in the text, the correspondingly stronger function classes are required.

Comment: Does it mean that even the $\delta$ function which has a differentiation order of $n=1$ could be  a diffeomorphism?